# Need to produce custom html out of VIsual Web Part

Tags: visual-web-part, html

I have to use Visual Web Part that retreives data from sharepoint list and produces some custom html. I want then to render that custom html as part of the Visual Web Part. 
Here is the html that I need to render as part of my web part

```
'<iframe frameborder=' + '"' + '0' + '"' + 'scrolling=' + '"' + 'no' + '"' + 'src=' + '"' + playerUrl  +'"' + 'width=' + '"' + '100%' + '"' + 'height=' + '"' + '100%' + '"' + '</iframe>');
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Do you need guidance on the Visual Web Part or the Asp.Net conventions?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar when I needed to override properties of a Page Viewer Web Part.

The key is to use the `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38128/inherited-page-viewer-control-allowtransparency-on-iframe